# Can't access index file in spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the following controller.

```
package com.school.project;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String AllUsers(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("listUsers", userService.getAllUsers());
        return "users";
    }

}
```

and an `index.html` file placed in my templates folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Manager Site</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{webjars/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>username</th>
                    <th>password</th>
                    <th></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But whenever I launch my application, I get the following error.

```
Sat May 20 18:57:06 IDT 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template [users], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [users], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

If I change the routing of my index mapping, the html will load with no problem, but if I give them the same routing, I get that error.

It is the same error. I get if I try to go to a URL with no matching template file.

I know this error has already been posted, but none of the solutions worked for me.

My service class is the following.

```
package com.school.project;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
        return users;
    }
}
```

and my model class.

```
package com.school.project;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "user")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "isAdmin")
    private boolean isAdmin;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Show `index.html` for all routes that don't match anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the problem, The name of your file html should be the same name returned in your method AllUsers, so just replace index.html by users.html.

Answer (score 1):

Update the file with the following content: html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Manager Site</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Password</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="user : ${listUsers}">
                        <td th:text="${user.id}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${user.email}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${user.name}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${user.username}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${user.password}"></td>
                        <td><!-- additional actions if needed --></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I just tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to change anything :(

Comment: I think that's because of HttpStatus 500, you have a problem related to your database and jpa, you can check your connection with the database. and maybe the problem is because your methods in your service so check your methods getAllUsers, ...

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tested that by changing the controller into a Rest controller and having the method return the answer and it returned a json like expected

Comment: i think i found the problem i fotget to see the name of your file html, it's should be the name of the return of your function AllUsers, so just replace index.html by users.html.

Comment: thanks to issam el orf, that seems to have "fixed" the problem, but now I have the new problem of the table not containing any of the elements in my database.

Anyhow could you make your comment into a response so that I can mark the question as solved?

Once again thanks

Comment: You're welcome, I want to ask you if you use my code html or not !! you should use it because your code html is fault

Comment: Yes I'm using your code. Unfortunatly the users in my database are still not showing

Comment: Check if your entity's attributes have the some names in html file i mean ( id, email, name, ...)

Comment: I checked again and the names match, I think it might have something to do with me missusing model.addatribute(params) because I just can't think of any other place where it could have gone wrong